# What happens with the local changes on svn export from working copy

Tags: svn, export

I am developing a web-site and keep its code an SVN. For development purposes I have two local copies:
1. A normal working copy that is always at HEAD (I am the only developer)
2. svn export'ed copy for the final tests and uploading to the server

svn export from the server guaranteed that exported directory is identical to HEAD, but takes hell a lot of time
svn export from the working directory is super-fast, but I am not sure what happens if there are some uncommitted changes in the local copy.

Does anybody know what happens if I try svn export from the working directory and there's some of the following?
1. I just forgot to commit local changes (file addition/deletion/modification)
2. I deleted/moved the whole directory by mistake (i.e. together with .svn folders)

Will svn export from a working copy still produce a full clone of HEAD and/or stop with some error message if it's impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
svn export -r BASE /path/to/wc /path/to/export
```

By specifying BASE for the revision you will export the pristine version from the working copy.  Uncommitted edits will not be included.  Uncommited adds will not be included.  Unversioned files will not be include.  Uncommitted deleted files will be included.

Answer (score 5):

From [SVN docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html):

> `svn export [-r REV] PATH1[@PEGREV] [PATH2]`
>
> ...exports a clean directory tree from the working copy specified by `PATH1` into `PATH2`. All local changes will be preserved, but files not under version control will not be copied.